# Can I ask questions about OpenGL here? Or should I take them to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am reluctant to post this on Overflow since they mostly do not answer noobish questions. But I have an issue understanding of "how to put together" what I learned and need some advice how to proceed with the design of my game in OpenGL 3. I am doing this for the learning experience and the fun, I am not a professional. So where is the correct place to ask this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about OpenGL are welcomed here, however, like Stack Overflow, we handle *specific issues*, and by this I mean that if you ask about "what to learn next", or very broad question, it will be closed.

If your question is along the lines "I have this piece of code, and this other piece of code, and I'm trying to do XYZ, but it does not work for reason ABC [or it does not work and it gives me GHJ instead], what am I doing wrong?", generally the question is not downvoted and not closed.

I guess the thing to do would be to ask the question and see if it gets closed, then ask what you could do to improve it if it does.

Comment: Well, I do have a specific issue. My question is basically how to properly set up my VBO and what information I should lay out in it. As in, Vertices, Color, Position and Viewmatrix or if I should chose another approach. Basically, I am unsure how to set up OpenGL properly to have a "proper" 2D Environment.

Comment: @Assylum From my experience, I think your question fits this site and will not be closed.

Comment: @Assylum - just to add to this: I would strongly suggest searching here first to see if your issue is answered in a previous question; VBO setup, layout & usage is quite a common topic and even an on-topic question remains subject to being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/what-is-the-best-practice-for-data-in-a-vbo My thread was more or less well received and answered over on computergraphics. Thanks for the additional information though.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexandre points out, we *do* take OpenGL questions (we even have an [opengl](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl) tag with over 3000 questions), though we do have [additional requirements to consider such questions on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

On the off chance that you wish to ask a question regarding OpenGL that may not necessarily be on-topic either here, or at Stack Overflow; it is worth noting that there *is* a [Computer Graphics Stack Exchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/). Once again, you want to [ensure your question is on-topic for their scope](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but given they focus *specifically* on computer graphics, you might find them more lenient in assessing questions specific to OpenGL.